# Unity3d and Threading

Tags: c#, multithreading, io, unity-game-engine

I want to do some stuff in my app that is time consuming but which does not have an impact on the actual game. Therefore I am trying to use a thread to run that stuff separately. Here is how I create my thread:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(() => WriteCheckpointTextFile (myFileName, checkpoint));
thread.Start();
```

Here is the code I am running in WriteCheckpointTextFile:

```
void WriteCheckpointTextFile (string fileName, Checkpoint checkpoint)
{
            string checkpointToText = "";
            checkpointToText += CheckpointDataNames.nextMarker + Environment.NewLine;
            checkpointToText += checkpoint.nextMarker + Environment.NewLine;
            checkpointToText += "%" + Environment.NewLine;

            checkpointToText += CheckpointDataNames.difficulty + Environment.NewLine;
            checkpointToText += checkpoint.difficulty.ToString () + Environment.NewLine;
            checkpointToText += "%" + Environment.NewLine;

            checkpointToText += CheckpointDataNames.musicObject + Environment.NewLine;
            checkpointToText += checkpoint.musicObject + Environment.NewLine;
            checkpointToText += "%" + Environment.NewLine;

            checkpointToText += CheckpointDataNames.gameTimePassed + Environment.NewLine;
            checkpointToText += checkpoint.gameTimePassed.ToString () + Environment.NewLine;
            checkpointToText += "%" + Environment.NewLine;


            checkpointToText += CheckpointDataNames.storedStats + Environment.NewLine;
            checkpointToText += EndRaceDataString (checkpoint.storedStats);
            checkpointToText += "%" + Environment.NewLine;

            checkpointToText += CheckpointDataNames.pursuers + Environment.NewLine;
            foreach (PursuerData p in checkpoint.pursuers) {
                    checkpointToText += p.pursuerName + "," + p.pursuerNextMarker + "," + p.pursuerPosition.x.ToString () + "," + p.pursuerPosition.y.ToString () + "," + p.pursuerPosition.z.ToString () + Environment.NewLine;

            }
            checkpointToText += "%" + Environment.NewLine;
            #if !UNITY_WEBPLAYER

            System.IO.File.WriteAllText (fileName, checkpointToText);

            #endif
            Debug.Log("Finished writing text to file");
}
```

Now for some reason that last debug doesn't always get printed and my file is not always written. What could be causing this?

Comment: You could always add more debug prints to see where exactly it's stopping. Try wrapping the WriteAllText method in a try-catch and log away the exception. Also, how does your code behave if you're using async and await?

Comment: Is your process terminating or just not printing to the debug window?

Comment: I will add a few more debugs to find out exactly where it stops. writealltext is not trowing any exceptions as far as I can see but let me get back to you.

Comment: In Unity3D you have to be very careful with threads, there are many functions which have to be executed on main thread, otherwise you get some warnings/errors. The other tricky part is that many operators are overwritten and even simply null comparison could be not thread safe.

There is also a good library for unity3d threading: http://unitygems.com/threads/. Maybe you can compare how it is done there.

Comment: So I have added a few more debugs in my function and I now see the thread doesnt do anything after: checkpointToText += EndRaceDataString (checkpoint.storedStats);

Comment: So what exactly your `EndRaceDataString` function does?

Comment: Exactly the same as WriteCheckpointTextFile minus the writing to file. It turns my end race data into a string to be stored.

Comment: Also it stops at different times. Sometimes some debug calls show, other times they don't.

Comment: @kUr4m4: I'm pretty sure an exception is being thrown _somewhere_ in there. Wrap the function in a `try/catch` block and write out the caught exception to the `Debug.Log`; it will give you better information to work from.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair will do

Comment: @kUr4m4: Also, what's the type of `checkpoint.storedStats`? I'll bet money that it's a collection (like `List<Stat>`) and you're iterating it in your `EndRaceDataString` method with a `foreach(var stat in storedStats)` loop and it's throwing an `InvalidOperationException` saying "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute"

Comment: Wow, you would win your bet! Here is the exception: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that your collection `checkpoint.storedStats` is being modified from another thread (likely you're main thread) while you're iterating on it in your background thread. This throws an `InvalidOperationException`. Because your code is executing on a background thread, the exception is being silently thrown, unhandled, and ignored by the Unity player/engine.

Unfortunately, this means you'll have to synchronize or restrict access and changes to your `checkpoint.storedStats` collection so that only 1 thread may make modifications to it and while doing so, other threads must not be iterating on it.

It's difficult to comment on the best or simplest method for you to implement because I don't know how you use the `storedStats` collection throughout your application. One possible, and fairly typical solution would be to wrap all places access the collection with a [`lock` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx). This will ensure that only 1 thread enters the locked block(s) at any given time. Then when accessing the `storedStats` for *reading* (not *writing*) you can provide a method on your GameObject's script to `lock` the collection, make a copy of it, and return that copy. Since it's a copy, you can safely iterate on it:

```
public class Checkpoint : MonoBehaviour
{
    //used for locking
    private readonly object ThreadLocker = new Object();

    private List<Stat> storedStats = new List<Stat>();

    public List<State> GetStoredStatsCopy()
    {
        lock(ThreadLocker)
        {
            //makes a copy/snapshot of the list
            return new List<Stat>(storedStats);
        }
    }

    //sample code that changes storedStats
    public void AddStat(Stat newStat)
    {
        lock(ThreadLocker)
        {
            storedStats.Add(newStat);
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that the `Checkpoint` script now makes `storedStats` *private*. I've also added some sample method that *modifies* or *writes* to that underlying `storedStats`. So *all* access to that `storedStats` is controlled and threads are synchronized. This way your background thread can't be iterating on the `storedStats` collection (because it has a copy, and the creation of the copy is controlled/thread-safe) and any writes to the collection cannot occur at the same time as another thread is accessing it.

EDIT: And with the above API change, your calling code might look like:

```
checkpointToText += EndRaceDataString (checkpoint.GetStoredStatsCopy());
```

Comment: Awesome, I will try to implement your solution. I think making a copy of storedStats should be all I need because I actually only care about the data at the time I am storing it. Anything that is added later on, I don't care since it would have been generated after the checkpoint. I will mark this as correct as soon as I can figure out how to implement it :) Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: @kUr4m4: Unfortunately, you'll still have to put the locking in even if you're making a copy: the act of making the copy can throw the same error (because it needs to iterate on the `storedStats` collection to make the copy) if the collection is modified while making the copy.

Comment: Ok, I will look at the lock as well, but I can see already that making the copy of every list inside my custom class seems to remove the exception that was being thrown (just luck I guess and the fact that copying it is a much faster process than what I am doing with the lists). I will mark the solution correct since you have detected the problem and provided a more than adequate solution! Thank you again!